# mocha test for aws lambda returns TypeError: lambda.handler is not a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I do have a node.js AWS Lambda with a handler defined as

```js
 exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
// code goes here
 }
```

Lambda works fine.
Trying to create a unit test with mocha/sinon for the lambda which is defined in index.test.js.
I can access several functions from index.js from within index.test.js as I did import index.js and I added an export to index.js for exporting functions.
But when trying to call lambda.handler I do get an error: TypeError: lambda.handler is not a function.
Any idea why? It is exported, isn't it?

```js
const lambda = require('./../index');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const assert = require('assert').strict;
const sinon = require("sinon");

var lambda_event = {
// some test event
};

describe("lambda", function () {
  let ensureSecret;

  beforeEach(function () {
    ensureSecret = sinon.stub(lambda, "ensurePrivateKeyForApi");
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    ensureSecret.restore();
  });

    describe("send valid jwt", function() {
        it("should generate allow policy", async function() {
            // some more omitted code    
            //...

            //this line throws error: TypeError: lambda.handler is not a function
            lambda.handler(lambda_event, {}, function(a, b){});
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What's the output of lambda variable when you put a console.log(lambda) ? I am doing exact same thing in my lambdas and don't get any errors.

Comment: it giving me type undefined

Comment: starting with a fresh mind today it looks like the exports is causing the problem...
You cannot have exports.handler and then in addition export other functions in a module.exports statement.
I now switched to one single 
`module.exports = {
    handler,
    ensurePrivateKeyForApi,
    setPrivateKey,
};`
and defined handler as `function handler(a,b,c){}` that seems to work